# Building dynamic where condition in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause, dynamic-sql

I want to build custom Where condition based on stored procedure inputs, if not null then I will use them in the statement, else I will not use them.

```
if @Vendor_Name is not null
    begin 

    set @where += 'Upper(vendors.VENDOR_NAME) LIKE "%"+ UPPER(@Vendor_Name) +"%"'

    end
    else if @Entity is not null
    begin
    set @where += 'AND headers.ORG_ID = @Entity'
    end
select * from table_name where @where
```

But I get this error

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'set'.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this :

```
Declare @Where NVARCHAR(MAX) 

...... Create your Where

DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX) 
Set @Command = 'Select * From SEM.tblMeasureCatalog AS MC ' ;

If( @Where <> '' )
   Set @Comand = @Command + ' Where ' + @Where

Execute SP_ExecuteSQL  @Command
```

I tested this and it Worked

Answer (score 9):

You cannot simply put your variable in normal SQL as you have in this line:

```
select * from table_name where @where;
```

You need to use dynamic SQL. So you might have something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE 1 = 1 ';
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

IF @Vendor_Name IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL += ' AND UPPER(vendors.VENDOR_NAME) LIKE ''%'' + UPPER(@VendorNameParam) + ''%''';
    END
ELSE IF @Entity IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL += ' AND headers.ORG_ID = @EntityParam';
    END;

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@VendorNameParam VARCHAR(50), @EntityParam INT', 
                    @VendorNameParam = @Vendor_Name, @EntityParam = @Entity;
```

I assume your actual problem is more complex and you have simplified it for this, but if all your predicates are added using `IF .. ELSE IF.. ELSE IF`, then you don't need dynamic SQL at all, you could just use:

```
IF @Vendor_Name IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    Table_Name
        WHERE   UPPER(vendors.VENDOR_NAME) LIKE '%' + UPPER(@Vendor_Name) + '%';
    END
ELSE IF @Entity IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    Table_Name
        WHERE   headers.ORG_ID = @Entity;
    END
```

Answer (score 3):

old question but want to add that i just found using

`where 
    CASE WHEN @id = 0
        THEN 1
        ELSE id
    END 
    = 
    CASE WHEN @id = 0
        THEN 1
        ELSE @id
    END`

this is from these steps:

`where id = @id`

check if @id is null (or invalid) or have valid value so replace @id using case:

```
where id = 
CASE WHEN @id is null
    THEN 0
    ELSE @id
END
```

this is will end up as

```
where id = 0 -- if @id is null, still affected your query
where id = @id -- if @id have valid value
```

because we want use this "where" clause only if have valid data then we change id too

```
where 
CASE WHEN @id is null
    THEN 0
    ELSE id
END 
= 
CASE WHEN @id is null
    THEN 0
    ELSE @id
END
```

then will end up as

```
where 0 = 0 -- if @id is null and it doesn't affect your query
where id = @id -- if @id have valid value
```

don't forget if id is varchar, use 0 as '0'

```
CASE WHEN @id is null
    THEN '0'
    ELSE id
END
```

i use this in my project and working well, even i use more than 1 of this in one query. please let me know if this query costing time at larger data

Answer (score 1):

No need to use ad-hoc query (execute `SP_ExecuteSQL`)

Check below logic, you can use N number of dynamic / un-sure parameters / conditions

```
    -- flages
declare @chk_vendor bit;
declare @chk_entity bit;

-- setting off
set @chk_entity = 0;
set @chk_vendor = 0;

if @Vendor_Name is not null
        begin 
            set @chk_vendor = 1;
        end
    else if @Entity is not null
        begin
            set @chk_entity = 1;
        end


SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (UPPER(vendors.VENDOR_NAME) LIKE '%' + 
       UPPER(@Vendor_Name) + '%' OR @chk_vendor = 0)
  AND (headers.ORG_ID = @Entity OR @chk_entity = 0)
```

I am posting this answer as there many [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943136/sql-dynamic-condition-in-where-clause) , remember flag will just enable or disable a condition

Comment: The chk_vendor and chk_entity are mutually exclusive. So instead of an IF/ELSE shouldn't it be just IF condition for each of them?

Comment: You can also avoid the BIT variables altogether. (UPPER(vendors.VENDOR_NAME) LIKE '%' + 
       UPPER(@Vendor_Name) + '%' OR (@Vendor_Name IS NULL))
  AND (headers.ORG_ID = @Entity OR (@Entity IS NULL))