# Dynamically switching on/off WHERE boolean expression(s) based on a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, boolean-expression

I use SQL Server 2012 `SELECT` inside a stored procedure. SP takes a number of parameters. One of those parameters is important in context of my question. Here is a pseudo-code of my SP:

```
create proc MyProc
    @mid tinyint,
    @param1 bit = 0
as

    set nocount on

    select
    p.RowId,
    i.Sku,
    i.Condition,
    p.OldPrice,
    p.Delta

    from Prices p 
    join Items i on (p.Sku = i.Sku)

    where
    (p.Mid = @mid)
    and (i.Quantity > 0)
    and (i.IsNew = 0)

    --The condition below must (not)execute depending on param1
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    and not (p.Delta = 0 and p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    and p.ThreadId = @thread_id
    order by p.Delta desc
```

In other words, if `param1 = 0` the query executes WITH condition, if `param1 = 1` then the condition is ignored (like it wasn't there at all!).

I tried to play with boolean expressions but I still don't get the idea.

P.S. I dont't want any dynamic SQL like in this article: [Building dynamic where condition in SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090870/building-dynamic-where-condition-in-sql-statement). I love my pre-compiled SPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include a check in your where clause such that if when `@param1 = 1` then you don't care about the condition you wish to ignore.

```
((@param1 = 1) or not (p.Delta = 0 and p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin))
```

Lets take the case of `@param1 = 0`:

```
==> ((0 = 1) or not (p.Delta = 0 and p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin))
==> (false or not (p.Delta = 0 and p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin))
==> not (p.Delta = 0 and p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin)
```

Now lets case the case of `@param1 = 1`:

```
==> ((1 = 1) or not (p.Delta = 0 and p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin))
==> (true or not (p.Delta = 0 and p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin))
==> true
```

Full modified statement:

```
create proc MyProc
    @mid tinyint,
    @param1 bit = 0
as

    set nocount on

    select
    p.RowId,
    i.Sku,
    i.Condition,
    p.OldPrice,
    p.Delta

    from Prices p 
    join Items i on (p.Sku = i.Sku)

    where
    (p.Mid = @mid)
    and (i.Quantity > 0)
    and (i.IsNew = 0)
    and ((@param1 = 1) or not (p.Delta = 0 and p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin))
    and p.ThreadId = @thread_id
    order by p.Delta desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using or conditions, if the first statement in the or evaluates to true the second will not be tried

```
..... 
where  @param1 = 1 or 
       ( 
          p.Mid = @mid 
          and  i.Quantity > 0 
          and  i.IsNew = 0 
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just include another condition in the WHERE clause, and if `param1` is 1, have the whole expression evaluate to TRUE. The `OR` operator is a very convenient way to do this.

```
 AND ( @param1 = 1 OR ( NOT ( p.Delta = 0 AND p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin ) )
```

---

When `@param1 = 1` evaluates to TRUE, then it doesn't matter what the expression following `OR` evaluates to... TRUE, FALSE or NULL/ It doesn't matter because all three of these:  1) "`TRUE OR FALSE`",  2) "`TRUE OR NULL`", and 3) "`TRUE OR TRUE`" evaluate to `TRUE`.

Note that doesn't guarantee us that the expression following the `OR` won't ever be evaluated. We can say that the *result* of the expression following the `OR` will be ignored when `@param1 = 1` is TRUE. But SQL Server is free to evaluate the expression following the `OR`. We don't have control over that.

In some scenarios, the evaluation could throw an error. So in that sense, the expression isn't entirely gone. In this particular example, I'm not seeing what possible errors that expression might throw, but that's mostly because I'm not seeing the datatypes of the columns, and I can't know what implicit datatype conversions SQL Server might be performing.

---

As far as passing a `BIT` type as an argument, I'm not familiar with the nuances of that.

But I would suggest that we make the datatype conversion explicit in the SQL

```
 AND ( @param1 = CAST(1 AS BIT) OR ( NOT ( p.Delta = 0 AND p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin ) )
```