# SQL - Dynamic Condition in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following stored proc. The issue I'm having is with the "conditions" parameter. Basically each condition is its own column so it it passed in like this-

@Conditions = ' AND hcc_108 = 1 AND ...' etc.

I'm trying to do something like this-

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[GetPatientPanelList] 
(
@CareProviderId int=null, 
@Patient nvarchar(60)=null, 
@Conditions varchar=null,
@LocationId int=null

) 

AS

if @Conditions is null

SELECT *
FROM vw_patient_attributes t1
INNER JOIN STG_OSHODS_DW.osh_rpt.dim_member_care_measures t2
    ON t1.PatientID = t2.emr_id
WHERE
(t1.PreferredServiceLocationID = @LocationId OR @LocationId IS NULL)
AND (t1.CareProviderID = @CareProviderId OR @CareProviderId IS NULL)
AND (t1.FullName like '%' + @Patient + '%' OR @Patient IS NULL) 

else

SELECT *
FROM vw_patient_attributes t1
INNER JOIN STG_OSHODS_DW.osh_rpt.dim_member_care_measures t2
    ON t1.PatientID = t2.emr_id
WHERE
(t1.PreferredServiceLocationID = @LocationId OR @LocationId IS NULL)
AND (t1.CareProviderID = @CareProviderId OR @CareProviderId IS NULL)
AND (t1.FullName like '%' + @Patient + '%' OR @Patient IS NULL)
+ @Conditions
```

I just need the last AND condition to populate based off the parameter. I understand that the " + " is the syntax error but I can't seem to figure out a way on how to implement this.

Thanks!

**Update**

I have tried dynamic sql but it keeps saying "Command(s) completed successfully)"

Here is my current code. I wrote this in a separate window to first get the query to work.

```
DECLARE @where nvarchar(50) = ' and hcc_18 = 1'
,@sql nvarchar(MAX) ,
@CareProviderId int=null, 
@Patient nvarchar(60)=null,
@LocationId int=null

set @sql = 'select *
FROM vw_patient_attributes t1
INNER JOIN STG_OSHODS_DW.osh_rpt.dim_member_care_measures t2
ON t1.PatientID = t2.emr_id
WHERE t1.PreferredServiceLocationID = IsNull('+ convert(varchar,@LocationId) +',t1.PreferredServiceLocationID)
AND (t1.CareProviderID = isnull(' + convert(varchar,@CareProviderId)+ ', t1.CareProviderID)
AND (t1.FullName like %' + @Patient + '% OR ' + @Patient + ' IS NULL)' + @where  

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring `varchar` without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should always provide a length for all `varchar` or `nvarchar` variables/parameters. -- your `@Conditions varchar` is defaulting to a length of `1`. http://rextester.com/SDHW82771

Comment: Structure that's easier to read and should perform better: `t1.PreferredServiceLocationID = isnull(@LocationId, t1.PreferredServiceLocationID)`

Comment: gonna need dynamic sql

Comment: Dynamic SQL may be a better option for varying search conditions - http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: I posted my dynamic sql that I tried earlier. At first I got conversion errors, then when I added in the converts, it just said "command(s) completed successfully".

Comment: This looks like it would be crazy vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn in the front end it is a multiselect. So from the multi select it is passed in as a string array, then I wrote a function to format the conditions to be " AND col1 = 1 AND col2 = 1.. etc".

Comment: See this article about this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ It explains how to write the dynamic sql so it not wide open to sql injection. And don't be confused....just because the front end is a multi-select this is vulnerable.

Comment: Then you should abstract what the front end is doing into a safer way to call that procedure.

Comment: it's because when you use + on a null column it returns null, thus your entire statement is null....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the syntax issues in your last updated. This should work...

```
DECLARE @where nvarchar(50) = ' and hcc_18 = 1'
,@sql nvarchar(MAX) ,
@CareProviderId int=null, 
@Patient nvarchar(60)=null,
@LocationId int=null

set @sql = 'select *
FROM vw_patient_attributes t1
INNER JOIN STG_OSHODS_DW.osh_rpt.dim_member_care_measures t2
ON t1.PatientID = t2.emr_id
WHERE t1.PreferredServiceLocationID = case when '+ convert(varchar(8),isnull(@LocationId,0)) +' = 0 then t1.PreferredServiceLocationID else ' + convert(varchar,isnull(@LocationId,0)) + ' end
AND (t1.CareProviderID = case when ' + convert(varchar,isnull(@CareProviderId,0)) + ' = 0 then t1.CareProviderID else ' + convert(varchar,isnull(@CareProviderId,0)) + ' end
AND (t1.FullName like ''%' + isnull(@Patient,'') + '%'' OR ' + isnull(@Patient,0) + '=0)' + @where  

print(@sql)
--exec(@sql)
```

Comment: No problem @KrazyDev

Answer (score 0):

[Check my answer at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090870/building-dynamic-where-condition-in-sql-statement/72808676#72808676)

No need to use ad-hoc query (just execute `SP_ExecuteSQL`)

Check below logic, you can use N number of dynamic / un-sure parameters / conditions........

Comment: This should have been a comment. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32138608)